# Visual Studio 2013 - .NET provider for HANA not visible in entity model

Tags: visual-studio, hana

I have to use entity framework with HANA database in visual studio 2013. I am following below steps-
1. I already have Visual studio 2013 professional edition installed on my desktop.
2. I downloaded SAP HANA client package from SAP market place and installed the same on my desktop.
3. I opened a new visual studio solution and tried adding ADO.NET entity model as shown below-

[image]

4. Then go to connection in the next screen as shown below-
   [image]
5. In the above image, i am not able to see ".NET Framework Data Provider for SAP HANA in the Data Provider dropdown even though i have the client installed.

Can someone help me finding out where i am going wrong ?

**Observation-**

1. I am able to see HANA provider when i go into server explorer and add a new data connection there as shown below-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share that i found the solution to above problem. The issue was related to OS bit.

We have 64 bit windows operating system and Visual studio is always 32 bit. Since i had installed only 64 bit HANA client, HANA provider was not visible in VS2013.

Once i installed both 32 and 64 bit HANA client, the provider came in the dropdown.
Got the reference from this URL-

[SAP HANA Client Interface Programming Reference](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0eec0d68141541d1b07893a39944924e/2.0.00/en-US/469de1336d6110148c9feec83dbeb4f0.html)